# What are the logout from all devices strategies with cookie based authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logout, asp.net-core-3.1, cookie-authentication

Which shouldn't also rely on `Identity` or `IdentityServer` concepts, maximum a DB Table for storage.
Searched around and can't find something like that.

Comment: Store an encrypted hash of all of a user's authentication cookies in a database table. When user accesses, check authentication cookie against encrypted hash. When "logout from all devices" is invoked, remove all of the user's hashes from the table.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I can't even get the encrypted cookie from the HttpContext in the first place, do you know how to do that?